# Dynamic SQL = [Err] 42000 - [SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '01'

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Here is my code:

```
DECLARE @1day AS VARCHAR(MAX), @sqlText AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @firstdate AS DATETIME

SET @firstdate = DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(GETDATE())-1),GETDATE()) 
SET @1day = CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), @firstdate, 103)

SET @sqlText = 'SELECT ' + 'Dummy' + ' AS ' + @1day

EXEC (@sqlText)
```

I am getting the error: [Err] 42000 - [SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '01'.

Expected result is:

```
01/06/2013
==========
Dummy
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Are you looking to have the date shown as column name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enclose both `Dummy` and `@1day` with single quote otherwise `@1day` is incorrect syntax for column alias and `Dummy` is interpreted as column name.

Valid SQL:

```
DECLARE @1day AS VARCHAR(MAX), @sqlText AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @firstdate AS DATETIME

SET @firstdate = DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(GETDATE())-1),GETDATE())
SET @1day = CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), @firstdate, 103)

SET @sqlText = 'SELECT ' + '''Dummy''' + ' AS ''' + CAST(@1day as nvarchar) + ''''

exec (@sqlText)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
DECLARE @1day VARCHAR(MAX), @sqlText NVARCHAR(MAX), @firstdate DATETIME

SET @firstdate = DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(GETDATE())-1),GETDATE()) 
SET @1day = CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), @firstdate, 103)

SET @sqlText = 'SELECT ' + '''Dummy''' + ' AS [' + @1day + ']'

EXEC (@sqlText)
```